# Typescript & Javascript language features extension in VSCode causes my laptop to overheat

Tags: visual-studio-code

It's been like a month since I started using VSCode and I like it.
However, The problem is the moment I launch the program the laptop's fans start to make relatively loud sounds so I thought because there were multiple programs running at once but after trying to launch VSCode alone the problem remains untacked. 
Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Disabled the gpu accelartion.
2. Disabled all the built-in extensions except the `Typescript & Javascript language features extension` (I didn't install any additional extensions)
3. Tried clean install.

Nothing worked, **But** when I tried to disable `Typescript & Javascript language features extension` the fans started to cool down. I even checked the system monitor. The reading of CPU usage for VSCode before and after disabling the mentioned extension
It jumped from 0% to 28% to 30% to 16% and keeps bouncing between 9% and 16% for as long as the application is running.

I know it seems obvious to disable this extension and I'm good to go but I need it, I mean the whole point of me using VSCode is this extension. Did anyone run into the same problem or it's only me?

P.S: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: You should file a bug report: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So after decades of research this guy's [answer](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22702#issuecomment-398871461) solved the problem.

All you have to do is to open `VSCode` then `File > Preferences > Settings` then type the following in the search bar `typescript.disableAutomaticTypeAcquisition` then `check` the checkbox and you're good to go.

However, autocomplete is not working for some imported packages so be aware of that.

Anyway, I opened an issue long time ago if anyone wants to follow any new updates about this topic [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36950).

Go and give this guy's answer a thumbs up or love because he deserves it.

Comment: You save my time, Thanks!